# Unity overriding a virtual method and adding one statement to the if

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem,
I have 3 classes, one is a base class from which two other inherit,
the base class has a method with a counter,
if the time runs out it should destroy gameObject,
but other classes should have this method but in this conditional statement you could was to add anything
I just want to add an extra command to if from another class.

If you don't understand, feel free to ask, because I'm not good at explaining.

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
 

        public virtual void DestroyByTime()
        {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timeLeft <= 0)
            {
                 /*
                 This statement should only be added in class B
                    |
                    v
                  gameSession.GameOver();
                 */
               
                
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            DestroyByTime();
            
        }
    }
```

```
public class B : A
{
 

        public override void DestroyByTime()
        {
        
         /*
           
          I want the base class if to be saved, but in if statement time runs out you lose
           (gameSession.GameOver())
         */

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an OnTimeOut method an override only in derived class:

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void DestroyByTime()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft <= 0)
        {
             OnTimeOut();
            
             Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnTimeOut()
    {
        // Do nothing here
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        DestroyByTime();            
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void OnTimeOut()
    {
        gameSession.GameOver();
    }
}
```